# Получение списка Bluetooth устройств в Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Делаю простое Android приложение, которое будет работать с Bluetooth. Но при выполнении команды на получение списка Bluetoth устройств
(`pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()`),
возвращает 0. Т.е. устройств не найдено. Но при этом хоть одно (моё) должно быть.
Вот код:

Инициализация адаптера
[image: Инициализация адаптера]

Манифест

[image: Манифест]

Визуализация команды

[image: Визуализация команды]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается я гений, который пытался получить устройства с эмулятора андроид, а не со своего телефона... Фейспалм...

Comment: `getBondedDevices()` вернет вам список уже спаренных устройств на вашем телефоне. Это так на всякий случай :)

Comment: попросил бы вас ответ свой принять галочкой, чтобы спустя время бот не апал вопрос как неотвеченный

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Господи... Это уже 2й фейспалм в одном моем проекте. Может Вы подскажите, нормальный ресурс где адекватно описано получение списка блютуз устройств?

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov Уже

Comment: Вот этот цикл 1-4 статей очень качественный: https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-1-a736dcd53b02

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja большое спасибо! Удачи!)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja ещё раз здравствуйте. Сделал уже всё по правильному (Как я понял), но к сожалению мой bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery не хочет находить устройства для подключения. Хотя getBondedDevice() работает. Есть ли возможность у Вас помочь?)

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос, опишите чего хотите достичь и код как вы это делаете. В случае поиска конкретного устройства вам `startDiscovery` не нужен, используйте лучше сканер из статьи.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja понял, благодарю!